# Python Wave byte data

Tags: python, audio, wave

I'm trying to read the data from a .wav file.

```
import wave
wr = wave.open("~/01 Road.wav", 'r')
# sample width is 2 bytes
# number of channels is 2
wave_data = wr.readframes(1)
print(wave_data)
```

This gives:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Which is the "first frame" of the song. These 4 bytes obviously correspond to the (2 channels * 2 byte sample width) bytes per frame, but what does each byte correspond to?

In particular, I'm trying to convert it to a mono amplitude signal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to understand what the 'frame' is you will have to read the **standard** of the wave file format. For instance: https://web.archive.org/web/20140221054954/http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/wave.htm

From that document:

> The sample points that are meant to be "played" ie, sent to a Digital to Analog Converter(DAC) simultaneously are collectively called a **sample frame**. In the example of our stereo waveform, every two sample points makes up another sample frame. This is illustrated below for that stereo example.

```
sample       sample              sample
frame 0      frame 1             frame N
 _____ _____ _____ _____         _____ _____
| ch1 | ch2 | ch1 | ch2 | . . . | ch1 | ch2 |
|_____|_____|_____|_____|       |_____|_____|
 _____
|     | = one sample point
|_____|
```

To convert to mono you could do something like this,

```
import wave

def stereo_to_mono(hex1, hex2):
    """average two hex string samples"""
    return hex((ord(hex1) + ord(hex2))/2)

wr = wave.open('piano2.wav','r')

nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes, comptype, compname =  wr.getparams()

ww = wave.open('piano_mono.wav','wb')
ww.setparams((1,sampwidth,framerate,nframes,comptype,compname))

frames = wr.readframes(wr.getnframes()-1)

new_frames = ''

for (s1, s2) in zip(frames[0::2],frames[1::2]):
    new_frames += stereo_to_mono(s1,s2)[2:].zfill(2).decode('hex')

ww.writeframes(new_frames)
```

There is no clear-cut way to go from stereo to mono. You could just drop one channel. Above, I am averaging the channels. It all depends on your application.

Comment: Thank you, that link was very informative, and entertaining to read.

Answer (score 5):

For wav file IO I prefer to use scipy.  It is perhaps overkill for reading a wav file, but generally after reading the wav it is easier to do downstream processing.

```
import scipy.io.wavfile
fs1, y1 = scipy.io.wavfile.read(filename)
```

From here the data y1, will be N samples long, and will have Z columns where each column corresponds to a channel.  To convert to a mono wav file you don't say how you'd like to do that conversion.  You can take the average, or whatever else you'd like.  For average use

```
monoChannel = y1.mean(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

As a direct answer to your question: two bytes make one 16-bit integer value in the "usual" way, given by the explicit formula: `value = ord(data[0]) + 256 * ord(data[1])`.  But using the `struct` module is a better way to decode (and later reencode) such multibyte integers:

```
import struct
print(struct.unpack("HH", b"\x00\x00\x00\x00"))
# -> gives a 2-tuple of integers, here (0, 0)
```

or, if we want a *signed* 16-bit integer (which I think is the case in .wav files), use `"hh"` instead of `"HH"`.  (I leave to you the task of figuring out how exactly two bytes can encode an integer value from -32768 to 32767 :-)

Comment: The `struct` module is very useful in this case. So much better than the hex/ord/decoding mess in my answer. I had no idea it existed.

Comment: I believe the bytes are little-endian, which requires that you use the syntax `struct.unpack("<hh", b"\x00\x00\x00\x00")` (according to [this link](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/wave.htm)). Also, according to the same link, 16 bit sample width implies signed data, 8 bit sample width implies unsigned data, which agrees with what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to convert 2 bytes into an int16, use numpy.fromstring(). Here's an example:
audio_sample is from a wav file.

```
>>> audio_sample[0:8]
b'\x8b\xff\xe1\xff\x92\xffn\xff'

>>> x = np.fromstring(audio_sample, np.int16) 

>>> x[0:4]
array([-117,  -31, -110, -146], dtype=int16)
```

You can use np.tobytes to convert back to bytes